# removing 0 after decimal 4th digit

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an excel file with coordinates. I want to take only the first 3 digits if the fourth digit is 0 after the decimal.

```
Original data    Output required
12.6820701       12.682
-0.58903705      -0.589
56.345698        56.345698
8.95604          8.956
21.99911         21.99911
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please don't post images. Recreating the reproducible from images is tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['Output required'] = df['Original data'].astype(str).apply(lambda v: round(float(v), 3) if ('.' in v and len(v) >= v.find('.')+4 and v[v.find('.')+4] == '0') else float(v))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
Original data    Output required
12.6820701       12.682
-0.58903705      -0.589
56.345698        56.345698
8.95604          8.956
21.99911         21.99911
```

Comment: getting error.df['output'] = df['Latitude'].astype(str).apply(lambda v: round(float(v), 3) if ('.' in v and len(v) >= v.find('.')+4 and v[v.find('.')+4] == '0') else float(v))
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: i tried but it is still not showing the correct result. I want 34.70406448 to 34.704 but your code is doing  34.704000

Comment: That's not my code's fault actually - Pandas automatically displays extra zeros at the end of decimal number so that all numbers look like the same length. There are 3 extra zeroes in `34.704000` because you have some other number that has 6 decimal places that aren't 0.

Comment: so can you please guide what to to do now.